# LDRMIB in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I am studying ARM Assembly from a library file. I was looking through some random functions and I found these load instructions which I didn't understand their syntax.

Here is it:

```
LDRMIB   R1, [R5, R3]
LDRMIB.W R2, [R2, #-0x24]
LDRPLB.W R1, [R2, #-0x24]
LDRPLB   R2, [R5, R3]
```

What is the differences from an original LDR instruction?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to a snippet with pre-UAL syntax, don't do that for learning purposes.

From [ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0406b/index.html):

`LDRMIB` -> `LDR` `MI` `B` Load, Minus/negative, Byte

`LDRPLB` -> `LDR` `PL` `B` Load, Plus, positive or zero, Byte (this is pre-UAL syntax), With UAL it should read `LDRBPL`.

> > Load Register Byte (register) calculates an address from a base register value and an offset register value, loads a
> >     byte from memory, zero-extends it to form a 32-bit word, and writes it to a register.

`LDRMIB.W` -> `LDRMIB`, `.W` for instruction to be encoded as 32-bit.

Comment: LDRPLB can be rewritten to LDRBPL (pre-UAL syntax) as you said. So, why LDRMIB can't be rewritten to LDR B MI which MI is minus?

Comment: because the instruction is `LDRMIB`, single word. MI is not minus, it is accronym for Multiple Increment, and B is for Before not Byte or something else. Go to ARM ARM for instructions, no where else.

Comment: Unless the syntax has been heavily changed in the last few years I'm pretty sure `LDRMIB` would be `LoaD (word) (if) MInus, Byte`. A `LoaD Multiple Increment Before` would be written as `LDMIB` (note the lack of an `R`), and would have a register list (`{...}`) as its second operand.

Comment: @Michael oh, how embarrassing, let me fix that.